# How to change treeview default expand/collapse image c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

1. I need to change tree node default image that expand & collapse image which is (`+/-`). How could I use my own image instead of default (`+/-`) plus & minus image for expand & collapse?
2. How to capture any node expand or collapse?
3. When any node will expand then I want to change node image for the time being and the moment child node will be loaded under expand node then revert back the previous image for that node. Just want to mimic on demand node population or loading data under any node.

Can you guide me with some code for my 3 question?

Thanks